# Vaadin chart order bars

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-charts

This is my chart:
[image]

Now, bars are sorted by series(on right side) but I want to sort every category by values like that:

[image]

Can I do that with Vaadin charts?

Answer (score 1):

Current behavior is that bars follow the order in which the series are added.

Unluckily I don't think it's possible to change the order of the bars for each category, and it's a limitation in the underlying charting library.